# Get the most unmatched values from two List<T> using LINQ by C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have list following:

```
public class matrix
        {
            public string Row { get; set; }
            public string Column { get; set; }
            public int Value { get; set; }
        }
```

So, in my main method the two list is following which have different values

```
List<matrix> matrixList1 = new List<matrix>();

List<matrix> matrixList2 = new List<matrix>();
```

Now I have tried so many times to find the most unmatched data from that two list where the values of the three properties ie. Row, Column and Value will be different using LINQ. Actually i am looking for the non-matched values from that two list 'matrixlist1' and 'matrixlist2'
`where (matrixlist1.Row != matrixlist2.Row && matrixlist1.Column != matrixlist2.Column && matrixlist1.Value != matrixList2.value)`. Could you please help me regarding this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "find the most unmatched data" here.  Are you looking for entries in `list1` that do not match entries in `list2` because `Row` or `Column` or `Value` don't match?

Comment: Use a left outer join.  See following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you are trying to do.

Comment: no, actually i am looking for non-matched values from the two list 'matrixlist1' and 'matrixlist2' where (matrixlist1.Row != matrixlist2.Row && matrixlist1.Column != matrixlist2.Column && matrixlist1.Value != matrixList2.value).

Comment: no, actually i am looking for the non-matched values from that two list 'matrixlist1' and 'matrixlist2' where (matrixlist1.Row != matrixlist2.Row && matrixlist1.Column != matrixlist2.Column && matrixlist1.Value != matrixList2.value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

`var uniqueItems = matrixList1.Where(l1 => !matrixList2.Any(l2 => l1.Row == l2.Row && l1.Column == l2.Column && l1.Value == l2.Value))`

Comment: Be sure to Concat the corresponding query for `matrixList2.Where(l2 => etc)`.

Comment: Exactly, thats what i need. Thank you so much. Every time, i have missed to Concat the corresponding query & thats why i did not get the proper answer. Anyway, thank you so much again.